# What is difference between ENV.fetch with block or with second param?

Tags: ruby

I'm not sure whether:

```
ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
```

and:

```
ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS", 5)
```

are the same or not. What is the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that the missing variable name is yielded to the block.

In your example, the result is the same because you do not use the yielded string, but try this to see the difference:

```
ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS", 5)
#=> 5

ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { |missing_name| "Could not find env var named " + missing_name }
#=> "Could not find env var named RAILS_MAX_THREADS"
```

Comment: So it's a way to set a custom exception message?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know it's only used to set custom messages.

Comment: Another difference is that the block's code is only evaluated if the key is missing.

Comment: @Stefan: that's the main one, I'd say

Comment: NB @LeticiaEsperon, it is not a way to supply a custom exception message, it provides a different way to return a default value. The example given above happens to look like an exception message, but it would not be raised. It would be returned as the value.